# Restream hls(m3u8) using ffmpeg, hls-server and reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I would like to create server with hls video (m3u8 file), so if I write in browser http://localhost:4000/stream/video.m3u8 I would like to get video.m3u8 file. I trying this, but it doesn't work for me live.js:

```
var ffmpeg = require('../index');
var HLSServer = require('hls-server')
var http = require('http')

var server = http.createServer()
var hls = new HLSServer(server, {
  path: '/streams'
})
server.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('HLSServer ready on htpp://localhost:4000')
})

const command = ffmpeg('https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8')
  .outputOptions([
    '-hls_time 10',
    '-hls_playlist_type event',
    `-hls_segment_filename %03d.ts`,
    '-hls_base_url http://localhost:4000/'
  ])
  .output('/streams/outputfile.m3u8')
  .on('progress', function (progress) {
    console.log('Processing: ' + progress.percent + '% done')
  })
  .on('end', function (err, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log('Finished processing!' /*, err, stdout, stderr*/)
    // console.log(stdout)
  })
  .run()
```

UPDATE:

Console log:

```
HLSServer ready on htpp://localhost:4000
Processing: 1.213% done
Processing: 4.231% done
...
```

But file `outputfile.m3u8` is nowhere created, files with `.ts` extensions too. If I delated line `'-hls_base_url http://localhost:4000/'`. File outputfile.m3u8 is saving on disk (but VLC still can't open file...nothing doing)...I would like to can get `outputfile.m3u8` from writing in browser : `http://localhost:4000/streams/outputfile.m3u8`. Because now I get 404 error (no page)

UPDATE2 :
logs from console when I running :

`ffmpeg.exe -i "https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8" -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_segment_filename %03d.ts -hls_base_url http://localhost:4000 outputfile.m3u8 -loglevel verbose` in `cmd` :

[Log1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHdAV.png) [Log2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8n33.png) [Log3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fp67I.png)

UPDATE3:

When I changed command to : `.\ffmpeg.exe -i https://bitdash-a.akamaihd.net/content/MI201109210084_1/m3u8s/f08e80da-bf1d-4e3d-8899-f0f6155f6efa.m3u8 -hls_time 10 -hls_playlist_type event -hls_segment_filename %03d.ts -hls_base_url http://localhost:4000 http://localhost:4000/outputfile.m3u8 -loglevel verbose`

in log I got error : `URL read error: Error number -10053 occurred`

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Question is Why this code doesn't work? I get 404 code when I try open http://localhost:4000/streams/outputfile.m3u8

Comment: Please update the question to describe the error you are receiving, along with all relive that info such as directory listings, http headers and ffmpeg logs.

Comment: @szatmary Updated with all information which I have

Comment: Please post the ffmpeg log.

Comment: @szatmary I'm using fluent-ffmpeg library for node.js and I can't find nowhere log file, but I added logs from console with the same request

Comment: But that’s not the same. It being run form a different location, possibly with different permissions.  Is possible ffmpeg is not able to write to the serving directory. Or is writing to a different directory than you think, or not even starting at all. Do you see the ffmpeg PID when this is running?